# Is it possible to record yourself while reading?

Tags: video-recording

I'm looking for an app that allows me to display some text on the screen and lets me record myself with the front camera. I have to send in a recorded interview, however I'm finding it difficult looking at the camera/screen while glancing over my written notes.

Comment: Why you just not use an external source for reading? (like a monitor...) The angle is the key :)

Comment: Unless you're using HTC Desire EYE, there are better recording solutions that using a front camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need something like [Detective Video Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rivalogic.android.video) or [Secret Video Camera Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thang.secretvideorecorder). I use the second one, just make the desired adjustment for orientation.

Comment: Second app does the trick!